# how to open different reports into one report viewer control?

Tags: vb.net, report

What can be wrong in my code below?

```
Private Sub LocalReport(ByVal digito As Integer)

    Dim relatorioCorrente = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource()

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    If (digito = 1) Then
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewer.rpt1.rdlc"
        mcv_modbusTableAdapter.Fill(geradorxmlDS.mcv_modbus)
        relatorioCorrente.Name = "geradorxmlDS"
        relatorioCorrente.Value = mcv_malhaBindingSource
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(relatorioCorrente)
    ElseIf (digito = 2) Then
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewer.rpt2.rdlc"
        mcv_modbusTableAdapter.Fill(geradorxmlDS.mcv_modbus)
        relatorioCorrente.Name = "geradorxmlDS"
        relatorioCorrente.Value = mcv_modbusBindingSource
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(relatorioCorrente)
    ElseIf (digito = 3) Then
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewer.rpt3.rdlc"
        mcv_registroTableAdapter.Fill(geradorxmlDS.mcv_registro)
        relatorioCorrente.Name = "geradorxmlDS"
        relatorioCorrente.Value = mcv_registroBindingSource
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(relatorioCorrente)
    End If
    ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

End Sub
```

This is the error that I am seeing:

> "Could not provide any data source instance to the data source"

Comment: What kind of issue are you running into?

Comment: the following error message appears: "Could not provided any data source instance to the data source" I'm trying to open multiple reports in a single report viewer control. I do not wish to have several forms in my program created for each report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don´t you try to create an instance?

Something like:

```
If (digito = 1) Then
   Dim relatorioCorrente = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource()
   Dim MyViewer as ReporViewer1 = New ReportViewer1**
   MyViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
   MyViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewer.rpt1.rdlc"
   mcv_modbusTableAdapter.Fill(geradorxmlDS.mcv_modbus)
   relatorioCorrente.Name = "geradorxmlDS"
   relatorioCorrente.Value = mcv_malhaBindingSource
   MyViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(relatorioCorrente)
   MyViewer.RefreshReport


ElseIf (digito = 2) Then
   same as above...

ElseIf (digito = 3) Then
   same as above
End If
ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```